# Ask the user to enter an integer that is over 500. Work out the square root of that number and display it to 2 decimal places

Tags: python, math

I've been asked to write a program which asks the user to enter an integer that is over 500. Then I need to work out the square root of that number and display it to 2 decimal places.

So far I have:

```
import math
number= int(input("Please enter a number over 500")
if number<500:
       print ("That's too low")
else:
      print (math.sqrt(number))
```

Everything works but where do I place the `print(round(number,2))`?

EDIT:
I typed the code, so YES the indenting is wrong.

Comment: What ever it is, this is not python

Comment: But assuming that you typed instead of copy pasting, just do `print (round(math.sqrt(number),2))`

Comment: I typed the code insdead of coping , so yes there will be capitalised letters and wrong indenting but  bare with me i'm new on here.

Comment: We will be a little easy on you since you are new, but you are still responsible to read and follow the guidelines on [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. You need to fix the indentation overall, the missing right parenthesis in the second line, and the misnamed `mumber` variable.

Comment: As a general rule, if you're rounding for output, *don't* use `round`: use string formatting instead. `round` is for the (rare) situations where you want to continue computing with the rounded value.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
import math

number = -1
while number < 500:
    number= int(input("Please enter a number over 500: "))
    if number < 500:
        print("Number entered is too low. Please enter a number that is larger than 500.")

print(round(math.sqrt(number), 2))
```

Basically, it keeps asking for user input until the value is larger than 500.

If you later want to add checking to not allow float numbers to be entered but only have them enter integer values you can do this by just changing the loop a little:

```
# Same as before
while number < 500:
    try:
        number= int(input("Please enter a number over 500: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("An integer value was not entered.")

# Same as before
```

Credits to [u/e4c5](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267540/e4c5) for the `round(math.sqrt(number), 2))`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure 'mumber' is fixed to say 'number'  and instead of

```
print(math.sqrt(number))
```

use

```
print(round(math.sqrt(number),2))
```